# CSS does not work

Tags: php, html, css, include

I have made a simple code to demonstrate my problem. I have two files:

**The first - main**

```
<p id="red">RED</p>
<?php
include("color.php");
?>
<style>
#red  {color: red};
#blue {color: blue};
</style>
```

**and the second one:**

```
<p id="blue">BLUE</p>
```

I want to change color for both paragraphs, but I do not do the same CSS code to the other .php file. Please, how can I do it? And why the code below does not work, when I included the other file there?

Comment: show us color.php please.

Comment: `<style>` should NEVER be a sibling of `<p>`

Comment: The css should be linked in <head>  as  <link rel="stylesheet"... or <style></style> also in head or inline, but never in body as <style> ... Form your example that's what I see. Good luck.

Comment: There are allot of variables as to why this wouldnt work, your include could be wrong or its not showing because you do not have Wamp or Lamp or Xamp on your computer, or if testing on a site you need to contact your hosting to see why it is not working.

Comment: Also if you want inline styling (GOD FORBID) do this <p style="color:red"></p>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code it's working

```
<style type="text/css">
#red  {color: red;}
#blue {color: #FF0;}
</style>
<p id="red">RED</p>
<?php
include("color.php");
?>
```

You put ; sign after } that's mistake.

Comment: Correct, the `;` is the reason.

Comment: before I downvote, I just tried it `<html><head><style type="text/css">
#red  {color: red;};
#blue {color: blue;};
</style>
</head>
<p id="red">RED</p>
<?php
include("color.php");
?>
</html>
`
And it didn't work. Did you run your code to double check?

Comment: i checked it but it's not work.. remove ; sign after style.

Comment: got it, just found that mistake. Have an upvote.